# C read file line by line into char**

Tags: c

I want to store data from a textfile into a char**.

**.txt File:**
First Line
Second Line
....

Now i would like to print second line like this:

```
printf("%s", lines[1]);
```

Here's my Code so far, but what's wrong here?

```
char* line = malloc(1000);
char** lines = malloc(10000);
FILE *file = fopen(file_path, "r");

int i = 0;
while(fgets(line, 1000, file) != NULL)
{
    lines[i] = line;
    printf("%s", line);
    i++;
}
free(line);
```

Comment: After this code has run, you've assigned the same pointer (`line`) to every element of the array `lines`, and then you free that pointer. EIther you have to allocate a fresh `line` for each line you read, or easier is to read the whole file into a buffer, set `lines[i]` to point into the right place in the buffer, and then replace each '\n' with a zero char. You can use `strchr` to help.

Comment: `malloc(10000)` is not right. If the maximum number of lines you handle is N, then you want `malloc(N * sizeof(char**))`.

Comment: You consistently read into the very same `line` buffer, and only store the address of its first byte in `lines`: at the end, all elements from `lines` will point to the last line.

Comment: "What's wrong here" is not a good statement of a problem. It would be better to describe what's happening when you compile the program (ideally with `-Wall` to catch all easy problems), and what happens or doesn't happen when you run the program with a particular input file.

Comment: A `char` is not a `char*` is not a `char**`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The common way for that is to consistenly read every line into the same buffer, and store a copy of that line in the lines array:

```
char line[1000]
int i = 0, nlines = 10000;
char **lines = malloc(nlines * sizeof(*lines));

while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), file) != NULL) {
    if (i == nlines) {      // must alloc more lines
        nlines *= 2;
        char **tmp = realloc(lines, nlines);
        if (tmp == NULL) {
            perror("Memory allocation error in realloc");
            break;
        }
        lines = tmp;
    }
    lines[i] = strdup(line);
    if (NULL == lines[i]) {
        perror("Memory allocation error in strdup");
        break;
    }
    ++i;
}
```

Provided you have enough available memory, the above code will accept as many line as you want, or will stop if no memory can be allocated any more, but still keep whatever has been read to that point.

The main limitation is that it will split lines longer than 998 characters (+ the newline and the terminating null)